# Tab Bar Icon Doesn't show when selected

Tags: interface-builder, swift5, xcode13

I have a tab bar controller and I have set both images using assets for selected and unselected icons. The icons show up correctly in interface builder

[image]

when I spin it up on the simulator and that tab is unselected, it shows something like:

[image]

But as soon as it's selected, it shows something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing view controllers along with tab bar controller and adding them again fixed this issue. Don't exactly know which setting was causing it but it got fixed by this method.